# Blazor Server : How do i generate href dynamically

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor Server Project with .net 7.
I want to render the following link in my grid grows.
Here the need is that only when user click the button, i want to run the code that will compose SAS token with URL and the it should open this dynamically generated URL, which has sas token valid for 1 minute.

```
 <a href="dynamically Generated when clicked on this link"  
      class="btn btn-primary ms-2 mt-1" target="_blank">View</a>
```

Based on the suggestion from answers (@sam and @Kurt Hamilton), this is what i came up with, but it load the new pgae by repalcing the current page, i want the page to be loaded in new tab or new window, looks like target option has no effect, since i am using navigation manager and preventing default.

```
<a href="#"
   @onclick:preventDefault="true"
   @onclick:stopPropagation="true"
   @onclick="@(async ()=> await ViewFile(fileInfo.FullFilePathAndName))"
   class="btn btn-primary ms-2 mt-1" target="_blank">View</a>
```

Comment: You're`ViewFile` method needs to call the ` JSinterop `open` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if thats even possible. However, in your case it would be best to use a onclick handler on the anchor tag and inside this handler use the NavigationManager to go to a dynamically generated URL. The href of the anchor tag in this case should be href="" to make sure the browser doesn't interfere with the NavigationManager when you click the link.

Here is an example:

```html
@page "/"

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<a href="" @onclick="OnClickHandler">View</a>

@code {
    private async void OnClickHandler()
    {
        var token = "77465691";
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", $"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{token}", "_blank");
    }
}
```

Comment: No offense, but I don't think this is necessary.  html already has a vanilla way of doing this.

Comment: @Bennyboy, you are missing the context here.
The ask is that URL should be generated when clicked and it should open in new page.
Can you show how you can do it is html vanilla way ?

Comment: @NSS, If I'm a browser, I'm going to red flag this site as potentially harmful.  You are not supposed to try to auto-navigate randomly generated links without informed user input, as this is malicious behavior. suitable only for pr0n sites and such.  What you SHOULD do is FIRST use an event to generate an actual link, which the user may THEN click if they want to.  If you try to circumvent security features, the result will be increased site maintenance-- when hacks that once worked are now correctly prevented.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a button with a click event handler.

1. Create a button with an `onclick` event handler

```html
<button type="button" @onclick="@OnButtonClick">
Click me to generate dynamic URL
</button>
```

2. Generate the URL in the event handler and use `NavigationManager` to do the navigating.

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@code {
  private void OnButtonClick()
  {
    string url = GenerateUrl();
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo(url);
  } 

  private string GenerateUrl()
  {
    // TODO: implement
    return "/";
  }  
}
```

**EDIT**

Since a requirement for you is to utilise normal anchor functionality (e.g. open in new tab), I would recommend that you link to a page that acts as a intermediary. The intermediate page would generate the link on initialize, and then redirect to the dynamic page.

1. Create a link to the intermediary page

```html
<a href="/my-link-generator" target="_blank">
Link to dynamic URL
</a>
```

2. Create the intermediary page

```
@page "/my-link-generator"

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@code {
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    string url = GenerateUrl();
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo(url);
  }
  
  private string GenerateUrl()
  {
    // TODO: implement
    return "/";
  }
}
```

Comment: It does work, but open the page by replacing the current widow, i want to open new tab or new window

Comment: Ah, you should have probably mentioned that in the original question. It's a legitimate point though. In that case it would take some more effort.

Comment: @NSS It might be better to slightly tweak your thinking. Create a link to a fixed page, but then let the target page do the dynamic link generation and redirect. This would allow you to have a standard link without trying to hijack any events

Answer (score 0):

Post from (Nb777) helped

await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync("open", ""https://www.google.com/"", "_blank");

Answer (score -2):

I think it's more instructional to consider what Blazor is.  It's a framework for generating html dynamically.  It does things in a super-cool and efficient way-- But ultimately, under the hood-- it's still just a browser displaying html.

Therefore, it's often better to just look for a vanilla html solution instead of trying to figure out how to do it in Blazor (with or without javascript):

```
<p>Open <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">GOOGLE</a>.</p>
```

If this doesn't work, it's because someone's browser settings don't WANT you to pop up a new page.  Respect this setting, and move on with your life.

Of course, instead of "google.com" you can put a link to whatever page you want, including a new document in your own site.